# only final element getting added to javascript object when adding multiple

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to add multiple values to a javascript object. This is what I'm doing:

```
            $scope.newMappings.sChannel = 'EST';
            $scope.newMappings.sFormat = 'HD';
            $scope.newMappings.sASIN = '';
            $scope.newMappings.sLocalDescription = '';
            insertList.push($scope.newMappings);
            $scope.newMappings.sChannel = 'EST';
            $scope.newMappings.sFormat = 'SD';
            $scope.newMappings.sASIN = '';
            $scope.newMappings.sLocalDescription = '';
            insertList.push($scope.newMappings);
            $scope.newMappings.sChannel = 'EST';
            $scope.newMappings.sFormat = '4K';
            $scope.newMappings.sASIN = '';
            $scope.newMappings.sLocalDescription = '';
            insertList.push($scope.newMappings);
            $scope.newMappings.sChannel = 'VOD';
            $scope.newMappings.sFormat = 'HD';
            $scope.newMappings.sASIN = '';
            $scope.newMappings.sLocalDescription = '';
            insertList.push($scope.newMappings);
            $scope.newMappings.sChannel = 'VOD';
            $scope.newMappings.sFormat = 'HD';
            $scope.newMappings.sASIN = '';
            $scope.newMappings.sLocalDescription = '';
            insertList.push($scope.newMappings);
            $scope.newMappings.sChannel = 'VOD';
            $scope.newMappings.sFormat = 'HD';
            $scope.newMappings.sASIN = '';
            $scope.newMappings.sLocalDescription = '';
            insertList.push($scope.newMappings);
```

However, only the final record is getting added. I'm only getting values for sChannel as 'Vod' and sFormat as 'HD' . Can anyone please tell what I'm doing wrong here.

Comment: You are just changing the same object over and over - you need to create a new one each time.

Comment: @csmckelvey can you give some example to help me understand what is wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create new object each time after adding in the list

```
$scope.newMappings={};
        $scope.newMappings.sChannel = 'EST';
                $scope.newMappings.sFormat = 'HD';
                $scope.newMappings.sASIN = '';
                $scope.newMappings.sLocalDescription = '';            
                insertList.push($scope.newMappings);

                $scope.newMappings={};

                $scope.newMappings.sChannel = 'EST';
                $scope.newMappings.sFormat = 'SD';
                $scope.newMappings.sASIN = '';
                $scope.newMappings.sLocalDescription = '';
                insertList.push($scope.newMappings);

                $scope.newMappings={};

                $scope.newMappings.sChannel = 'EST';
                $scope.newMappings.sFormat = '4K';
                $scope.newMappings.sASIN = '';
                $scope.newMappings.sLocalDescription = '';
                insertList.push($scope.newMappings);

                $scope.newMappings={};

                $scope.newMappings.sChannel = 'VOD';
                $scope.newMappings.sFormat = 'HD';
                $scope.newMappings.sASIN = '';
                $scope.newMappings.sLocalDescription = '';
                insertList.push($scope.newMappings);

                $scope.newMappings={};

                $scope.newMappings.sChannel = 'VOD';
                $scope.newMappings.sFormat = 'HD';
                $scope.newMappings.sASIN = '';
                $scope.newMappings.sLocalDescription = '';
                insertList.push($scope.newMappings);

                $scope.newMappings={};

                $scope.newMappings.sChannel = 'VOD';
                $scope.newMappings.sFormat = 'HD';
                $scope.newMappings.sASIN = '';
                $scope.newMappings.sLocalDescription = '';
                insertList.push($scope.newMappings);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in plain javascript.  Add your objects to a list.  You need to make each object separately.

```
var list = [
    { date: '04/1/2018', id: 3, user: 20055 },
    { date: '04/7/2018', id: 5, user: 20053 },
    { date: '04/11/2018', id: 6, user: 45652 }
];

alert(list[0].id);
```